# PHP include try catch

Tags: php

I need to make a code work but it doesn't seem to work at all. It is supposed to use the code from the page if it does exist, but if it doesn't then it redirects to a `404 page`.

```
try {
    include "/pages/". $_GET["page"] . ".php";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header("Location: /?page=404");
}
```

Comment: `if ( !@include('xxx') ) { /* redirect */ }`

Comment: Remember to send out status code 404 on your error page. Otherwise google might index it as a regular page.

Comment: @NULL I would not use `@` that will suppress any warnings/errors and is not a good practice. Its more of a hack than a solution

Comment: @GGio true, nothing else to say. Just filling out the minimum comment limit

Comment: this code is a recipe for desaster. Say your script is in the file called `index.php` and I call it from the browser with `index.php?page=../index`. => infinite recursion => denial of service. more damage may be done if someone really tries...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work. Include won't throw any exceptions.

You should simple do it this way:

```
$file = "/pages/". (isset($_GET["page"]) ?: $_GET["page"] :'')  . ".php";

if (file_exists($file)) {
   include $file;
}
else {
   header("Location: /?page=404");
   exit; // you should use it after redirection
}
```

Comment: Why post a comment as a answer?

Comment: @NULL Have you read the question? I don't see there any info that Exceptions need to be used

Comment: I see now that you wore hoarding to be #1 post, and have you read my comment? ;)

Answer (score 2):

include does not throw an exception and therefore it can not be used within try/catch. You can however check if file exists or not, and if it does not exist throw an exception which will be caught by try/catch block:

```
try {
   $path = "/pages/". $_GET["page"] . ".php";

   if ( ! file_exists($path)) {
       throw new \Exception('File does not exist');
   }

   include $path;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header("Location: /?page=404");
}
```

Or you can just remove try/catch and just use `file_exists`

Comment: Why not remove the try-catch all together?

Comment: @NULL I agree no need but in case he needs to have specifically exception handling.

Comment: @NULL there is nothing wrong with throwing exception and using try/catch. He could be using logger that logs exceptions to database.

Comment: @GGio http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
<?php
if ((include "/pages/". $_GET["page"] . ".php") !== 1)
{
    die('Include failed.');
}
?>
```

Or if you need catch an exception

```
<?php
if ((include "/pages/". $_GET["page"] . ".php") !== 1)
{
    throw new Exception("Include failed");
}
?>
```